# replicate browser session with selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there way to use same firefox browser session(if current browser crashed or closed) with selenium web driver?

Assume I have 1000 line of code to check and browser is crashed when I am debugging on line 800 and then IDE(eclipse) doesn't allow further debugging.So I have to fresh start again to test this.Is it possible to start a new browser session with the crashed point?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. The scenarios/test are and should be independent, when the scenario ends successfully or not, the session will end.

Anyway you would't want that, the scenario which should be independent, should pass or fail and not try-catch or do-while.

For browser chash issues you need to check the condition that leads to this and try to fix it and change the driver if needed with a stable one.

Reading the description of the questions made me think that maybe this is not the issue, the real issues being the the test is too long.

You might want you do a code review and see what you can improve.
Some general tips / best practices:
1. Keep each scenario as simple as possible
2. Every scenario must focus on a specific flow an check some specific results
3. The scenario/test should be executed fast
4. The scenario should be reliable and consistent with the results (stable)

Few bad practices:
1. When a scenario that checks to many things that are not covered in other scenarios fails will result in areas/functionality not being tested/covered
2. Loading the scenario with multiple checks in different places can increase the chance of failure since any of the checks might fail
3. From same reason as previous points, increasing the number of checks might give you the wrong idea when reviewing the results

Answer (score 1):

[QMetry Automation Framework](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/) provides feature to [use existing driver session](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/using_running_driver_session.html), which is quite helpful during automation development and debugging.

1. Create remote webdriver session
2. Use it for your execution by setting `webdriver.remote.session` property